# Transfer POAP (ERC-721) out of Gnosis Safe via SDK

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm using the JS SDK and trying to create a transaction that transfers out a POAP of a Safe... the tx goes through and I can see it in the UI, but not sure why it doesn't transfer the asset out
here's the safe's history with the txs that I've submitted to try and transfer the POAP out
https://gnosis-safe.io/app/gno:0x166fe3B49E82c0514689Ff0527Cd7C76261A9D07/transactions/history

here's the code:

```
const transferPOAP = async (safeAddress: string, toAddress: string) => {
  // NOTE :: Get POAPs in wallet
  const poaps = await getWalletPOAPs(safeAddress);
  // NOTE :: Get array of POAP Token IDs
  const tokenIds = poaps.map((el) => el.tokenId);

  // NOTE :: Create Gnosis Safe Factory
  const safeSDK: Safe = await Safe.create({
    ethAdapter: new EthersAdapter({
      ethers,
      signer: owner_wallet, // NOTE :: Owner of safe
    }),
    safeAddress,
  });

  // NOTE :: ABI encoded transaction data
  const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(
    {
      name: "safeTransferFrom",
      type: "function",
      inputs: [
        { type: "address", name: "from" },
        { type: "address", name: "to" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "tokenId" },
      ],
    },
    [safeAddress, toAddress, tokenIds[0]]
  );

  // NOTE :: Create transaction
  const safeTransaction = await safeSDK.createTransaction({
    safeTransactionData : {
      to: toAddress,
      value: "0",
      data,
    },
  });

  // NOTE :: Get transaction hash
  const txHash = await safeSDK.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);

  // NOTE :: Sign + Execute transaction
  const executeTxResponse = await safeSDK.executeTransaction(
    safeTransaction
  );

  // NOTE :: Get final confirmation of successful transaction
  const res = await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
  console.log(res?.transactionHash);
}
```

Comment: Is this because I am trying to interact with a contract that I am not the owner of, or have permission to interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [latest transaction entry](https://gnosis-safe.io/app/gno:0x166fe3B49E82c0514689Ff0527Cd7C76261A9D07/transactions/multisig_0x166fe3B49E82c0514689Ff0527Cd7C76261A9D07_0x020eb3d65e5ce385850e354a94c3092e32c08cb4eeeb777e0e2963c58516a3be) on your Safe, it appears you're attempting to make a contract call on the address [0x9bE27356765EA765F1503c9c63e227fAD8c0B8A9](https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/address/0x9bE27356765EA765F1503c9c63e227fAD8c0B8A9/transactions), which is an EOA.

To make calls on smart contracts, you must, of course, execute them on a contract (that supports the method). Looking at the [tokens assigned](https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/address/0x166fe3B49E82c0514689Ff0527Cd7C76261A9D07/tokens#address-tabs) to the Safe address, it seems the POAP token contract in question is [0x22C1f6050E56d2876009903609a2cC3fEf83B415](https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/address/0x22C1f6050E56d2876009903609a2cC3fEf83B415).

Therefore, submit your transaction again, but make sure the "to" field (that is, the contract you want to interact with) is this contract.